# xlrd Parse excel data to txt

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, txt

I am trying to manipulate a text from excel sheet to a txt file. I have am excel file with these data

```
101 | BL101 | eth1/1 | BL101-eth1/1
102 | BL102 | eth1/2 | BL102-eth1/2
103 | BL103 | eth1/3 | BL103-eth1/3
```

And I need to create a text file like this:

```
interface port-channel 101
description BL101
interface Ethernet1/1
description BL101-eth1/1

interface port-channel 102
description BL102
interface Ethernet1/2
description BL102-eth1/2
```

etc...

This is my code:

```
for row_idx in range(0, num_rows):
    for col_idx in range (0,num_cols):
        cell_obj = sheet.cell (row_idx, col_idx)
        print ('%s' % (cell_obj.value))
    print('--- END ---')
```

And I get these results

```
101
BL101
interface Ethernet1/1
BL101-eth1/1
--- END ---
102
BL102
interface Ethernet1/2
BL102-eth1/2
--- END ---
```

etc....

But I can't make it put some words (interface, description) between lines. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: One quick think I can guess is that you have to check eg the col_idx and if 0 print “interface port-channel” followed by the value of the cell at the first column (101) etc.

Comment: you can use vba .see https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/vba-blogs/vba-blog-create-text-file-from-excel-table

Comment: Thanks @YannisP.!! You clearing my mind!
I add new lines and work now!!

` if col_idx == 0:
            print ('interface port-channel %s' % sheet.cell (row_idx,col_idx))
            print ('desc %s' % sheet.cell (row_idx,col_idx + 1))
            print (': %s' % sheet.cell (row_idx,col_idx + 1))
            print ('switchport')
            print ('switch port mode trunk')
            print ('vpc %s' % sheet.cell (row_idx,col_idx))`

Comment: @Thorchin very nice to hear that it works for you now. Return to SO on future issues of yours!